# php and mysql - insert works but update not working

Tags: php, mysql

what is wrong with my code, as insertion works fine, but update not working. I have copied the updaet's query from phpmyadmin and changed static values to variable

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitContactInfo'])) {
    $socityId = $_SESSION['socityid'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `_abc1`.`profile` (SOCIETY_ID,ADDR,CITY,PIN,STATE,TEL,MOBILE,EMAIL) VALUES ('$socityId','$address','$city','$pin','$state','$telephone','$mobile','$email');";


    $sql = "UPDATE `_abc1`.`profile` SET `ADDR` = '$address', `CITY` = '$city', `PIN` = '$pin', `STATE` = '$state', `TEL` = '$telephone', `MOBILE` = '$mobile', `EMAIL` = '$email' WHERE `society_profile`.`SOCITY_ID` = '$socityId'; ";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @mcryan: no i am not getting any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your update. You have SOCITY_ID when in the first query it is SOCIETY_ID

try

```
$sql = "UPDATE `_abc1`.`profile` SET `ADDR` = '$address', `CITY` = '$city', `PIN` = '$pin', `STATE` = '$state', `TEL` = '$telephone', `MOBILE` = '$mobile', `EMAIL` = '$email' WHERE `SOCIETY_ID` = '$socityId'; ";
```

Also, as mentioned you should use mysqli_query instead of these old deprecated functions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, you should consider using mysqli or PDO rather than the standard mysql class.
- Secondly, you haven't joined a table, so how are you expecting it to match the two tables you're trying to query?

Comment: The second and third points are incorrect.  Double quotes are used on the outside, the the values of the variables will be interpolated into the string.  Only one table is used in both queries and the second query uses a known value to filter the update.

Comment: @G-Nugget On the third point: `WHERE \`society_table\`.\`SOCITY_ID\``

Comment: On the (now deleted) second point, I was unaware that you could use ' to escape a variable in a string.

Comment: I didn't see it that far into the query.  It was probably another typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$sql = "UPDATE '_abc1'.'profile' SET 'ADDR' = '".$address."', 'CITY' = '".$city."', 'PIN' = '".$pin."', 'STATE' = '".$state."', 'TEL' = '".$telephone."', 'MOBILE' = '".$mobile."', 'EMAIL' = '".$email."' WHERE 'society_profile'.'SOCITY_ID' = '".$socityId."'; ";
```

Comment: This should not make a difference since the queries use double quotes so the contents will be interpolated (the variables' values will be in the query, not the variable name).